# Index content does not show when I try to go online

Tags: javascript, firebase

I was successful deploying the website (I know because the logo icon shows on the tab and I followed the steps carefully) but the content of my website won't show. It's my firs time doing this and I'm pretty sure it's a small thing but I've been stuck for days. It's probably in my index.html. I'm using angular and firebase. please help!

I've looked at tutorials and of course the firebase documentation. Seems like it's an sdk issue or maybe the script tags at the end of my index.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>F2I</title>
  <base href="https://[" f2ifrance.firebaseapp.com/"> <meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- <base href="/"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bs-stepper/dist/css/bs-stepper.min.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
  <!-- firebase hosting SDK -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm almost there... I just need to see the content. Here's the error I have on my console and of course I googled it but couldn't find an answer. Thanks a lot to anyone who could help.

> Uncaught Error: hosting/init-error: Firebase SDK not detected. You must include it before /__/firebase/init.js

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the error message: you are including `init.js` before the Firebase SDK. Try this:

```
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

  <script src="/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```